# React JS Route to the same component with filtered data

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have navigation bar in which i have two links, linking to the same component which is a data table what i need to do is that when i click on other link it should filter the data on my table being on the same component. Can anyone help me out with it

Comment: Could you please show us what you have tried, some code or something?

Comment: Sorry, i can't show you the code